# Using Django template inheritance with ngroute - where does `<div ng-view>` go if I want to override blocks outside of `<div ng-view>`?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

This is my `base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html{% block html %}{% endblock%}>
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Base{% endblock %}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/angular.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/angular-route.js' %}"></script>
    <base href="/">
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
    </head>


    <noscript> <!-- If JS is disabled, the CSS below will run, causing everything inside "bodyContainer"
                to no appear and causing the "noscriptmsg" to appear. -->
        <style type="text/css">
            .bodyContainer {display:none;}
            .noscriptmsg {display: block;}
        </style>
    </noscript>
    <div class="noscriptmsg">
        <p>Please enable your browser's JavaScript in order to view this website.</p>
    </div>

    {% block body %}
        <span class='cerrorMessage' ng-bind="ctrl.cerrorMessages"></span>
    {% endblock %}
</html>
```

This is an example of a template which inherits `base.html` (call it `home.html`):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load static from staticfiles %}

{% block html %} ng-app="AuthenticationApp"{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/home.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl" class="bodyContainer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {{ block.super }}
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <form ng-submit="ctrl.change()" class="form-horizontal" name="myForm"></form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

{% endblock %}
```

The `html` block is to set the `ng-app` which will be used for the web page. The `head` block is to load the relevant JS and CSS files. The `body` block is where the body of the HTML page goes. However, I am using `ngroute` to load webpages. This is the routing and JS:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/new', {
    templateUrl: 'static/templates/new.html'
})

self.change = function() {
    $location.url("/new");
};
```

So in `home.html`, when the form is submitted, the URL changes to `/new` (which serves the page `new.html`. This is `new.html`:

```
{% block html %} ng-app="NewApp"{% endblock %}

{% body head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/new.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% body block %}
    <h5>NEW CONTENT</h5>
{% endblock %}
```

So for every template which inherits `base.html` and gets loaded, I want to be able to redefine / override the blocks again. Where do I put `<div ng-view></div>` so that I will be able to redefine the blocks with correct code structure?

I tried putting it in `home.html` (the page which the app loads first) right underneath `<div class="container"></div>`, but then it doesn't override the blocks. I can put it in `base.html` above / outside the `<html{% block html %}{% endblock %}>`, but that would be placing a `<div>` outside of `<html>` which isn't proper code structure. Any idea how to do this?